# Selenium Python find element xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I want to find with selenium this element:

```
<div ext:tree-node-id="Hard_to-find_object" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf ">
```

Is it possible?

```
//div[@ext:tree-node-id="Hard_to-find_object"]
```

doesn't seems to work for me. "Hard_to-find_object" is unique. Any hints?
Thank you.

EDIT: I have to find child of this element, so I need to use xpath.

Answer (score 0):

Use the selecector, they are usually easier. If the element has to load first then use the code here:

WebDriverWait(browser, 0.10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, Hard_to-find_object)))
browser.find_element_by_css_selector(Hard_to-find_object).click()

Comment: This isn`t working and I have to find child of this element, so I need to use xpath.

Comment: which language? and send a screenshot from the code

Comment: Python and browser console. It seems to be the ":" in attribute name that give me headache. With:
/div/@*[name()="ext:tree-node-id"]
 I can find "ext:tree-node-id", but can`t figure syntax to find the value "Hard_to-find_object".

Comment: without pictures it is hard to help you and locators actually always go

Comment: I can`t post pictures. In "<div ext:tree-node-id="Hard_to-find_object" class="x-tree-node-el x-tree-node-leaf ">" only "Hard_to-find_object" is changed. I will change the question to:
Is it possible to find attribute value if the attribute name contains : ?